# Quartz misfiring policies

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm new to Quartz in java and I have a question regarding misfiring. 
I have set up a SimpleTrigger which fires every 5 seconds. Sometimes the associated job takes over 5 seconds. I'd like to skip the job when that happens (the set interval has been reached by the Trigger). Going through the API I dont find a misfiring policy that would do that. 
Any toughts?
Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of different misfire policies that could work for you.  Look at the javadocs here: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.0/org/quartz/SimpleTrigger.html paying attention to the static final constants that start with MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_RESCHEDULE_*.  There are a number of different behaviors in regards to the repeat count, but I think they'll accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: None of the MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_RESCHEDULE_* options seems to instruct to cancel (or simply skip) the ongoing "long job" and trigger the next one. This results in the next job being delayed in exactly the amount of time delayed by the the "long job".

Comment: Ah...it wasn't clear that you wanted to cancel the long-running job.  In that case, no such functionality is provided. Quartz wasn't written with that kind of use case in mind, so you'll have to work for it.  First off, your job will need to be an instance of InterruptableJob : http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/InterruptableJob.html.  Then you'll need another Job or Thread periodically using the Scheduler API to interrupt your original job.  Or...you can write your own daemon (which may be easier).  Either way, make sure your job is interruptable!

Comment: That's a good idea. Thank you. Still, using Quartz, how would one handle a situation where the job (which normally takes less than the time set for the Trigger) takes longer than the time set for the Trigger. Are you supposed to just delay the entire schedule or even stall the entire schedule forever? I guess this can be a fairly common situation, right?

Comment: It definitely happens!  Unless your job needs to run in real-time, it should be okay to skip an execution once in a while and let it catch-up the next time around.  E.g. if you're processing DB rows for the last five seconds, modify the code to hit rows that have changed since the last time it ran (tracking the timestamp with the JobExecutionContext).  Of course, this strategy depends on the expected time of execution being less than the schedule interval as you say...otherwise things will pile up!  Also, since the Scheduler is multi-threaded, this job won't prevent other jobs from triggering.

Comment: Although real time would be optimal, it is just not going to happen. So, I’d be OK missing one execution here and there. I’m not sure I can do what you are suggesting. My problem is that sometimes once the Job execute() method starts (which contains the code that does the job) I don’t have a way to interact with the schedule (maybe I’m wrong). So, if that code takes forever to run, there is nothing I can do to stop it and move on to the next one. Is that the case?

Comment: If your job is an instance of InterruptableJob, you can cancel it after it's started via Scheduler's interrupt method. The thing is that you'll need to then have some sort of watchdog thread or other job to do the canceling. But that's starting to get nasty...I'd say you're better off making sure your job isn't able to run for too, too long.  Anyhow, it's hard to give too much more advice without getting into the specifics of exactly what it is you're trying to do!

Comment: No problem with making my Job and instance of InterruptableJob. I also agree having a thread that watches the job is not the way to go. What I don’t understand (again I'm new to Quartz) is why the scheduler does not keep an internal clock that watches the progress of the job and gives you control (through a Listner?) to intervene. Is this the case? It doesn't really matter what the job is (in my case computing some data which usually takes under 2 secs but in some case may take forever... not predictable; just the nature of the beast).

Comment: Hmm...you could try implementing a TriggerListener and cancel your job (if running) on the misfire event.  You would lose out on 5 seconds (or whatever your interval) of useable compute time, but perhaps it can work for your case of the runaway job.

Comment: I have looked into this and I don’t think there is a way to implement timeouts just with Quartz. I gave I try to the TriggerListener idea last week... it does not really work very well. I finally ended up implementing a job monitor (the idea we discussed earlier) which starts watching with a JobListener. It works great (for now). Still, it seems to me this should be part of Quartz.